# Why and how is it possible for a globalized BFGS implementation to not produce a descent direction towards the minimum?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

In my class we learned that the hessian matrix approximation used in the (inverse) BFGS method doesn't always produce a descent direction (same as newtons method) - but how and why?

Can someone give me hint in which situations the hessian matrix approximation has to be "resetted"?

Comment: Are you asking about a convex function or in general?

Comment: In general @JensRenders

Comment: In general, Newton's method (by extention also BFGS) tries to make the gradient zero. This can happen at maxima and saddle points as well, not just minima. If you require convexity of the function to be minimized than saddle points and maxima do not exist.

Comment: @JensRenders So what is the difference there between something like Conjugate Gradient or Gradient decent in general. As far as I remember correctly these methods also try to make the gradient zero?

Comment: You remember incorrectly. Gradient descent uses the fact that the gradient always points into the direction of steepest ascent. Thus taking a step in the direction of the negative gradient is taking a step down. The fact that this will also make te gradient zero in the limit is just a consequence of the fact that the gradient is zero in a local minimum.

Comment: @JensRenders If you say `tries to make the gradient zero` this comes down to the criteria you choose when the algorithm should terminate. Instead of `||\nabla f||_2` one can choose a different criteria? Or let me rephrase: How do we know that BFGS tries to make the gradient zero? As far as I know that's due to the termination criteria of the algorithm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108610/discussion-between-jens-renders-and-binarybigint).